# dz's Open Flash Chart 2 disabling animation problem (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, animation, open-flash-chart

How to disable the startup animation in OFC2? Since I started using the dz build, the on-show animation is on by default, which sucks quite a lot.

Neither of these work:

```
graph.animate=false

graph.on_show=false
```

Also, dz's build implements the tooltip hover support poorly - the tooltip continues to hover even when the cursor is on another flash object.

Has anyone overcome these problems?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: http://ofc2dz.com/OFC2/downloads/ReleaseNotes-Ichor.html

Basically just add {"on-show":{"type":""}

Example: (snippet of JSON) 
....
elements":[{"on-show":{"type":""},
.......